# All pair Maximum Flow

Tags: graph, max-flow, network-flow

Given a directed weighted graph, how to find the *Maximum Flow* ( or *Minimum Edge Cut* ) between all pairs of vertices.
 The naive approach is simply to call a *Max Flow* algorithm like Dinic's, whose complexity is `O((V^2)*E)`, for each pair.
Hence for all pairs it is `O((V^4)*E)`.

Is it possible to reduce the complexity to `O((V^3)*E)` or to `O(V^3)` by some optimizations?

Comment: PS: This is not home work.

Comment: Have you looked into Gomory–Hu tree ?

Comment: @mmgp : This is exactly want I wanted. Thanks! And can you post a link where the Gusfield's algorithm is described with examples and pseudocode?

Comment: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~kt/cut-tree/ the code can be found by visiting the Experiments link.

Comment: @mmgp Could you make the comment into an answer?

Answer (score 4):

Gomory-Hu Tree **does not work with directed graphs**, putting that aside, Gomory-Hu Tree will form a Graph maximum flow by applying minimum cuts.

The time complexity is:

```
O(|V|-1 * T(minimum-cut)) = O(|V|-1 * O(2|V|-2)) ~ O(|V|^2)
```

* using an optimal [minimum-cut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_cut) algorithm ([Max-Flow Min-Cut Reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem))

This [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gomory%E2%80%93Hu_tree#Example) illustrate how Gomory-Hu Tree is constructed from a given Graph

Comment: Gomory-Hu tree does not work for directed graphs(unless capacity (u,v)=(v,u) for all arcs).The cuts are not symmetric submodular functions, which is required for Gomory-Hu tree to work.

Comment: @ChaoXu Thank you for the comment, I'll note it in my answer.

Comment: You have T(min-cut) as O(2|V|-2) in your text.  What algorithm is that?  E-K is O(|V| * |E|^2) ~ O(|V|^5) and Dinic is O(|V|^2 * |E|) ~ O(|V|^4), leaving your Gomory-Hu build at O(|V|^5), not O(|V|^2).

Answer (score 3):

Gomory-Hu tree does not work for directed weighted graph.

It is an open problem whether there exist an algorithm to solve all pair maximum flow faster than running n^2 maximum flows on directed graphs.